# How can I transfer Django session authentication to my Vue frontend?

Tags: django, vue.js, authentication, session

My app uses Django and rest framework backend, Vue frontend. I would like users to use session authentication and login via Django's allauth, with its email verification and password reset support. On login, users are redirected to a Vue component, and I can put the CSRF token into request headers.

I need to get user object (or user ID) into my Vuex store at this point. Are these my choices, or are there others?

1. give up using session authentication and use JWT
2. put some kind of session data or token into localstorage that Vue could then retrieve. (How could I do this?)
3. somehow get user ID from CSRF token

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Duh. Sending request to view/endpoint for getting the authenticated user using Django's `request.user` worked like a charm, given that my Vue is also running on same localhost:8000 port as Django

in views.py:

```
class AuthUserView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        serializer = AuthUserSerializer(request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

in Vue:

```
methods: {
                getUser() {
                    fetch('/api/auth_user')
                        .then(response => response.json())
                        .then(data => console.log(data));
                }
            }
```

Comment: How secure it is? And where did you get the `AuthUserSerializer` function?